# How to convert excel data to json at frontend side

Tags: excel, user-interface

I want to convert some excel data to JSON. Plan is to get my excel file from D drive, read data and make some UI for this. Can any one please help me out?

Data is like this :-

```
country       year    1       2       3       4

Netherlands   1970    3603    4330    5080    5820
Netherlands   1971    3436    4165    4929    5693
Netherlands   1972    3384    4122    4899    5683
Sweden        1970    1479    1963    2520    3132
Sweden        1971    1497    1985    2547    3163
Sweden        1972    1419    1894    2445    3055
```

Comment: This question is too vague to be answered because you haven't specified a programming language or shown what you have tried first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could of course always use Excel VBA, as you are already working with Excel. The following sub exports the used range of the current sheet as valid JSON into a .js-file:

```
Option Explicit
Sub jsonex()
Dim fname, q$, str$, lineend$, na, va, ur As Range, i%, j%, ncols%, nrows%
Set ur = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
' set a few variables ...
na = ur.Rows(1): ncols = ur.Columns.Count: nrows = ur.Rows.Count: lineend = ",": q = """"

fname = "d:\tmp\data.js"                 ' prefedined filename 
' fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename  ' or use file selector box ...

Open fname For Output As #1
Print #1, "var data=["
For i = 2 To ur.Rows.Count
  va = ur.Rows(i)
  str = ""
  For j = 1 To ncols
    str = str & "," & q & na(1, j) & q & ":" & q & va(1, j) & q
  Next
  If (i = nrows) Then lineend = "];"
  Print #1, "  {" & Mid(str, 2) & "}" & lineend
Next
Close #1
End Sub
```

This produces the file `d:\tmp\data.js` with

```
var data=[
  {"Country":"Netherlands","year":"1970","1":"3603","2":"4330","3":"5080","4":"5820"},
  {"Country":"Netherlands","year":"1971","1":"3436","2":"4165","3":"4929","4":"5693"},
  {"Country":"Netherlands","year":"1972","1":"3384","2":"4122","3":"4899","4":"5683"},
  {"Country":"Sweden","year":"1970","1":"1479","2":"1963","3":"2520","4":"3132"},
  {"Country":"Sweden","year":"1971","1":"1497","2":"1985","3":"2547","4":"3163"},
  {"Country":"Sweden","year":"1972","1":"1419","2":"1894","3":"2445","4":"3055"}];
```

Once you got it in this JSON format it is up to you to convert it into a different Array/Object structure by using plain JavaScript like

```
var da={};
data.slice(1).forEach(function(e){
  var arr=[e[1],e[2],e[3],e[4]];
  if (!da[e.country]) da[e.country]={}
  da[e.country][e.year]=arr;
});
```

Maybe this is more the format you would like ("beautified" `JSON.stringify(da)`):

```
{"Netherlands":{"1970":["3603","4330","5080","5820"],
                "1971":["3436","4165","4929","5693"],
                "1972":["3384","4122","4899","5683"]},
 "Sweden":     {"1970":["1479","1963","2520","3132"],
                "1971":["1497","1985","2547","3163"],
                "1972":["1419","1894","2445","3055"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data could look like this:

```
[
 {"country":"Netherlands', "year":1970, "1":3603, "2":4330, "3": 5080, "4":5820},
 {"country":"Netherlands", "year":1971, ...}
 ...
]
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. But how i'll convert the excel data to this format

Comment: Either convert it manually or use a programming language.  You didn't specify how you wanted to do this in your question.

Comment: Programmatically. Using javascript, jquery or angular js

Comment: You can't read an Excel file from your D drive using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: You first need to save the data in a text format like CSV or tab delimited.  Then you need a different programming language (like Java, PHP, Perl, Python, etc.) to read data from that file and write it out as JSON.